# getting data from .ajax() function in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using a .ajax() function to call on a page and passing in data to it. What I don't understand is how to get the data and use it in the page that was called upon. Is there a function that I can call to retract the data?

Comment: $.ajax(url:"myurl.html",data: yourdata, success:function(data){....}); on the success yo can do whatever you want after response

Comment: I think the question is pointing more towards using data outside of the success function. Something King Arthur may have tried (and which wouldn't work) is `var response_data = $.ajax()`; expecting $.ajax() to return 'data' but it actually returns a 'jqXHR' object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html", //give your URL here
  data: {name:"your name"} , //(optional) if you wish you can send this data to server, just like this.
  success: function(data){
    $('body').prepend(data); //here is your data
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

Yes you can access the data that gets back from the page using jQuery's ajax callback.
I suggest your page return `jSon` data. If you provide which technique you use on the server side *PHP*, *Asp.NET* or other we can provide a full working example. Or did you want to load `html` ?

#### Sample

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(data){
    // data 
  }
});
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

You pass a function to the .ajax() as the `success` argument.  That function will be called with the data returned from the call.

**edit** Damn, lost another drag-race.